# kubernetes - Configmap - Existing files are removed

Tags: kubernetes, configmap

When using a ConfigMap as a mounted volume, all the existing files and folders inside the mounted location of the pod are deleted.

The ConfigMap is created using the command :

```
$ kubectl create configmap tomcat-configmap --from-file=./config/tomcat-config.xml
```

The deployement yaml file :

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: tomcat-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app: tomcat-container
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 83
    targetPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: tomcat-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: tomcat-container
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: tomcat-container
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: tomcat
        image: bitnami/tomcat:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        volumeMounts:
        - name: tomcat-configmap-volume
          mountPath: /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/examples/WEB-INF/classes/com/test/app-conf.xml
          subPath: app-conf.xml
      volumes:
        - name: tomcat-configmap-volume
          configMap:
            name: tomcat-configmap
```

I tried different config but without success :(

Any suggestion would be very helpful

I am using kubernetes provided with docker for windows :

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.3", GitCommit:"2bba0127d85d5a46ab4b778548be28623b32d0b0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-05-21T09:17:39Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}

Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.3", GitCommit:"2bba0127d85d5a46ab4b778548be28623b32d0b0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-05-21T09:05:37Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Comment: Can you provide the output of `kubectl describe configmaps tomcat-configmap`, if it's empty them you are doing something wrong.

Comment: kubectl describe cm tomcat-configmap  
Name:         tomcat-configmap  
Namespace:    default  
Labels:       <none>  
Annotations:  <none>  
Data  
====  
app-conf.xml:  
<apps>  
<app>  
<name>TEST1</name>  
</app>  
</apps>  
Events:  <none>

Comment: As you can see it is not empty. Do you have any suggestion or idea?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: tomcat-svc
spec:
  selector:
  app: tomcat-container
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 8080
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: tomcat-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: tomcat-container
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: tomcat-container
    spec:
  containers:
  - name: tomcat
    image: bitnami/tomcat:latest
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8080
    volumeMounts:
    - name: tomcat-configmap-volume
      mountPath: /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/examples/WEB-INF/classes/com/test
      #subPath: app-conf.xml
  volumes:
    - name: tomcat-configmap-volume
      configMap:
        name: tomcat-configmap
```

The answer provided above by Rico should work, anyways I am providing the implementation result below :

Comment out the subpath, subpath is really useful when you want to override an existing config file. Also, your tomcat path is /opt/bitnami/tomcat in the image that you are using, and you are mounting a file in a custom dynamically created location in /usr/local/tomcat/ , not sure what you mean by it is overriding the contents

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will give it a try and keep you informed

Comment: It works like a charme. It is sure that I was missing something. Thank y a lot

Comment: Done. Just to give more infos. The problem happens when the tomcat container run in non root user. I have a custom image based on tomcat and run with a particular user without privileges, and when I mount a volume based on configmap, the existing content is erased and the mounted file belong to root user.

Comment: You can run your container as non-root user say as tomcat user by setting USER tomcat in Dokcerfile, also if you want the permissions/ownership of the files that are being mounted to be as non default user, then you can refer this https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/ , here you define the user group id in fsgroup and the runas

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are using `subPath` and that's meant to be a directory and you are thinking `app-conf.xml` should be created as a file.

What you really want is just this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: tomcat-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: tomcat-container
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: tomcat-container
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: tomcat
        image: bitnami/tomcat:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        volumeMounts:
        - name: tomcat-configmap-volume
          mountPath: /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/examples/WEB-INF/classes/com/test
      volumes:
        - name: tomcat-configmap-volume
          configMap:
            name: tomcat-configmap
```

And name your file `app-conf.xml` so when you create the ConfigMap it gets assigned the `data` key `app-conf.xml` in your ConfigMap itself:

```
$ kubectl create configmap tomcat-configmap --from-file=./app-conf.xml
```

Then your ConfigMap will look like this:

```
$ kubectl describe cm tomcat-configmap
Name:         tomcat-configmap
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>

Data
====
app-conf.xml:
----
<xml>
...
...
</xml>

Events:  <none>
```

Comment: Thanks Rico for your answer.Unfortunately it doesn't work. Still facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

you did it right, you just missed the key parameter in your volume.
as you're trying to replace just one file with another, what I mean is that you're using subPath to replace just one file which in your case the file is "app-conf.xml" but you're not specifying which key in your configMap that would replace this file.
each configMap key is treated as an independent configuration file

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: tomcat-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app: tomcat-container
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 83
    targetPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: tomcat-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: tomcat-container
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: tomcat-container
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: tomcat
        image: bitnami/tomcat:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        volumeMounts:
        - name: tomcat-configmap-volume
          mountPath: /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/examples/WEB-INF/classes/com/test/app-conf.xml
          subPath: app-conf.xml
      volumes:
        - name: tomcat-configmap-volume
          configMap:
            name: tomcat-configmap
            key: <enter the key here>
```